# Google Sign In app identification

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

Imagine the following senario

User sign in my app using his google account.
What i need now is to grab his name, profile and background photo from his account.
User interact with my app and make a post to a server. (i am saving his name and avatar photo to the server) 
other users can see his post together with his profile name and avatar.

Now if user decide to change his profile photo or name how data on my server would reflect his changes ?
Cant figure out the flow of the above process.

Comment: This is the way I think as of now. You have to check and compare the photo URI and name, everytime User opens the app. Get PhotoURI and Name from Google Login, check it with your server. If not same then update your record in database.

Comment: @Chintan Soni
That is a nice implementation but if user changes his info and take a while to open up app other users should see stale data of him

Comment: Yes. You are right. For that, your server application have to do this job. Ask the person who wrote the Server Application, to write an agent that will keep running on Server, keep updating the database, accordingly.

Comment: I wrote the server app but i have no idea how to implement such an agent. Any further advise ?